# Get latest version of record in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the latest version for each record. For example I'm trying to get just version 2 of id 13 instead of both version 1 and 2, I've tried using a sub query with teh `MAX` function but it didn't make any different.

The primary key on the table `td_asset` is `PRIMARY KEY(ass_id, ass_version)`.

** SQL Query **

```
SELECT `ass_id` AS `id`
, `ass_title` AS `name`
, `ass_version` AS `version`
FROM `td_asset`
GROUP BY `ass_id`, `ass_version`
ORDER BY `id` DESC, `ass_version` DESC;
```

**SQL Query Result**

```
id  name        version
13  test name   2
13  test name   1
12  test name   1
11  test name   1
10  test name   1
9   test name   1
8   test name   1
7   test name   1
6   test name   1
5   test name   1
4   test name   1
3   test name   1
2   test name   1
1   test name   1
```

Any suggestions/ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is asked and answered endlessly, so yes, I have a suggestion.

Comment: @Strawberry, considering that I searched SO first and couldn't find anything with my search queries, I always search first so as to try not duplicate questions.

Comment: I can see a relevant answer about 9 cms that way ->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this question *is* asked a lot, it can be sometimes difficult to adapt other people's queries to your situation. So, one way to handle this is with a subquery.

```
SELECT
    tda.ass_id AS id,
    tda.ass_title AS name,
    tda.ass_version AS version
FROM td_asset tda
WHERE tda.version = (SELECT MAX(tda2.version) FROM td_asset td2 WHERE tda2.id = tda.id)
GROUP BY tda.ass_id
```

This essentially says, with each id, look up the max version and use that record.

There are other ways of solving this problem as well, this is just one of them.

Comment: No worries. Hope it helped.

Answer (score -2):

Just select `MAX(ass_version)` and group only by `ass_id`:

```
SELECT `ass_id` AS `id`
     , `ass_title` AS `name`
     , MAX(`ass_version`) AS `version`
FROM `td_asset`
GROUP BY `ass_id`
ORDER BY `id` DESC, `ass_version` DESC;
```